# Use '=' or LIKE to compare strings in SQL?

Tags: sql, comparison

There's the (almost religious) discussion, if you should use LIKE or '=' to compare strings in SQL statements.

- Are there reasons to use LIKE?
- Are there reasons to use '='?
- Performance? Readability?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

To see the performance difference, try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM master..sysobjects as A
JOIN tempdb..sysobjects as B
on A.name = B.name

SELECT count(*)
FROM master..sysobjects as A
JOIN tempdb..sysobjects as B
on A.name LIKE B.name
```

Comparing strings with '=' is much faster.

Comment: Woops... okay, I took the point.
Table with ~600 entries, 10 digit number as comparing field:
Equal is 20 to 30 times faster!

Answer (score 248):

`LIKE` and the equality operator have different purposes, they don't do the same thing:
`=` is much faster, whereas `LIKE` can interpret wildcards. Use `=` wherever you can and `LIKE` wherever you must.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE login LIKE 'Test%';
```

Sample matches:

> TestUser1
>   TestUser2
>   TestU
>   Test

Answer (score 46):

In my small experience:

"=" for Exact Matches.

"LIKE" for Partial Matches.

Comment: = is not case sensitive

Comment: In most RDBMS, the case sensitivity of = would depend on the collation settings of the relevant columns/tables/databases.

Answer (score 17):

There's a couple of other tricks that Postgres offers for string matching (if that happens to be your DB):

ILIKE, which is a case insensitive LIKE match:

```
select * from people where name ilike 'JOHN'
```

Matches:

- John
- john
- JOHN

And if you want to get really mad you can use regular expressions:

```
select * from people where name ~ 'John.*'
```

Matches:

- John
- Johnathon
- Johnny

Comment: As far as I am aware the regular expression and like keywords have worse performance than '='

Comment: Typo 'ilike' to 'like'

Answer (score 15):

Just as a heads up, the '=' operator will pad strings with spaces in Transact-SQL. So `'abc' = 'abc '` will return true; `'abc' LIKE 'abc '` will return false. In most cases '=' will be correct, but in a recent case of mine it was not.

So while '=' is faster, LIKE might more explicitly state your intentions.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Answer (score 10):

For pattern matching use LIKE. For exact match =.

Answer (score 6):

`LIKE` is used for pattern matching and `=` is used for equality test (as defined by the `COLLATION` in use).

`=` can use indexes while `LIKE` queries usually require testing every single record in the result set to filter it out (unless you are using full text search) so `=` has better performance.

Answer (score 4):

LIKE does matching like wildcards char [*, ?] at the shell
LIKE '%suffix' - give me everything that ends with suffix. You couldn't do that with =
Depends on the case actually.

Answer (score 4):

There is another reason for using "like" even if the performance is slower: Character values are implicitly converted to integer when compared, so:

declare @transid varchar(15)

if @transid != 0

will give you a "The conversion of the varchar value '123456789012345' overflowed an int column" error.