# Derby Query is very slow

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I am writing a query to load my data in a jlist

```
public void showtitle(){
  DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
  booklist.setModel(model);
  try{
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");    
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://"+X, "APP", "app");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query="SELECT TITLE FROM BOOK WHERE ISBN LIKE '%"
      + code.getText().toUpperCase()+"%' OR "
      + " TITLE LIKE '%"+name.getText().toUpperCase()+"%' ";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
      String isbn = rs.getString(1);
      model.addElement(isbn);
   }
  }
  catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Error!! Data cannot be displayed!" + ex);
  }
}
```

I am calling this method like this :

```
private void codeKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{                                 
  showtitle();
}
```

After inserting 1000 data my query is running very slow. Is my procedure not good? Is there some fatal mistake? What should I do?

Comment: I've found my error and solved like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing more than just executing a query in your method.

You're also creating the JDBC connection, which is probably a **much** more expensive operation.

Trying creating the JDBC connection once and saving it somewhere in your application.

Then when the user runs your key-released event, just run your query and fetch the results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your case doesn't really need the power of 'LIKE', maybe just use '=' instead? 'LIKE' is much mor powerful but may not be able to utilize indices, so you may end up performing a full table scan (see [Use '=' or LIKE to compare strings in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515039/use-or-like-to-compare-strings-in-sql) )