# Pull individual row value from SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a sql table that I need to extract certain data from. For example:
[image]

This is an example of my sql table and I would need to pull Monday's reds for a live tile for my application. And so on, I might need to pull Tuesday's reds or Tuesday's yellows.

Is there a query that can help me achieve this?

Comment: I am looking for sql code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monday's reds:

```
select Monday from SUMMARY where Key LIKE 'Reds' //Can also match wildcards, Slower
```

For tuesday's reds:

```
select Tuesday from SUMMARY where Key = 'Reds'  //Preferred , Faster
```

*Assuming SUMMARY is your tablename as per your comments.
Both ways work. 
See the difference between ***LIKE*** and ***=*** here : [Use '=' or LIKE to compare strings in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515039/use-or-like-to-compare-strings-in-sql)
Try them here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic query to do what you want, if I understand you correctly.  I'm assuming that the table headers are the column names.

Get monday's reds:

```
select [monday] from table where [key] = 'Reds'
```

Get tuesday's reds:

```
select [tuesday] from table where [key] = 'Reds'
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried the query and I am getting errors. I write SELECT [Monday] FROM SUMMARY WHERE [Key] = 'Reds' and get an error saying there is an error near the table name. not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Microsoft SQL Server?