# Searching between Two String Values

Tags: sql

Looking at this question on how to compare `String`'s in SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/515051/409976, let's say I have the following data, where START and END are String's.

```
ID START  END
1   1      5
2   A      C
```

I performed a query to search "between" these START and END values unsuccessfully:

`select * from TABLE where start <= '2' and '2' <= end -- 0 results`

or

`select * from TABLE where start <= 'B' and end >= 'B' -- 0 results`

Since I'm searching on alphanumeric, i.e. I can't just convert to an Int/Number, how can I perform the above two queries?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Do the values actually contain leading/trailing quotes as you show in your sample? If so, then you'll have to include them as part of the values that you're testing against. If not, then we need to know column definitions as well as DBMS version/release and possibly platform and even what client is used.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `ASCII()` to get the code value. It would work as long as your characters are within expected ranges etc.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(start) <= ASCII('2') and ASCII('2') <= ASCII(end)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(UPPER(start)) <= ASCII('B') AND ASCII('B') <= ASCII(UPPER(end))
```

Comment: ah, but `ASCII('3')` is > `ASCII('100')`.

Comment: "As long as your characters are within expected ranges". To be honest, for potentially alphanumeric output I would store everything as an INT and convert on display.