# How to grep the line by using the table contents in mysql?

Tags: mysql

---

here is mysql query which displays the entire table.

select * from datas;

```
name id dept
sen   1  cs
der   2  td
rest  3  ui
```

My query is i want to search by using table content(i.e in select statement i want to use the **word** **rest** and then display the table as follows).How can i do it in mysql?

Expected output:

```
name id dept
rest 3  ui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I don't understand why you can't just use the '=' :

```
SELECT * FROM datas
WHERE name = 'rest'
```

Although if you're truly looking for a grep equivalent, the [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) statement is where it's at :

```
SELECT * FROM datas
WHERE name LIKE '%rest%' --to select lines where rest is contained in the string
```

[Use '=' or LIKE to compare strings in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515039/use-or-like-to-compare-strings-in-sql)

Answer (score -1):

There many ways to do this

1.Use the WHERE clause just like this

```
SELECT * FROM datas WHERE id>2
```

2.Use LIMIT clause like this

```
SELECT * FROM datas LIMIT 2,1
```