# Increase performance query when use CONCAT in where clause

Tags: mysql, symfony

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE CONCAT(ud.first_name,' ',ud.last_name) LIKE 'John Smith%'
```

I created two index on first_name and last_name column, but I know they didn't work when use CONCAT in where clause because CONCAT scans full table.
Suppose I can't change table to create a new column as `full_name`. Is there anyway to increase performance in this case?

**Noted:**
Because the input can be any text such as first name, last name or full name so I use CONCAT and the full query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE (CONCAT(ud.first_name,' ',ud.last_name) LIKE 'search%') OR (CONCAT(ud.last_name,' ',ud.first_name) LIKE 'search%')
```

Comment: Why not `WHERE ud.first_name = 'John' AND ud.last_name LIKE 'Smith%'`?

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN contradicts WHERE condition by right table (joining type is converted to INNER).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to always use concat, then just create function index rather then indexing to separate columns

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON user_Details (CONCAT(ud.first_name,' ',ud.last_name));
```

otherwise I suggest you splitting rather than concatenation

```
WHERE ud.first_name = '?' AND ud.last_name LIKE '?%'
```

Comment: Functional indexes needs MySQL 8.0.13 and higher.

Comment: Your 2nd query will not return rows where, for example, `first_name='John Smith'`.

Comment: Unless the OP specifically declares, I presume it  version 8+. It has been long time that mysql 8 is out

Answer (score 0):

You tried if it is faster with :

```
ud.first_name = 'John' AND d.last_name like 'Smith%'
```

The comparison on the first string already may abort and equals is faster than like.

see also: [Use '=' or LIKE to compare strings in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515039/use-or-like-to-compare-strings-in-sql)

Comment: Your query will not return rows where, for example, `first_name='John Smith'`.

Comment: True! For first_name='John Smith' and last_name='' it will not return any item. But this is not clean data. When you want to cover such cases then I propose to clean the data before optimizing the query.